# get an element of a matrix

Tags: java

I have a matrix of object and I want to get an element of it giving the int of the place.

```
Computer matrix[][]=new Computer[rows][cols]

public Computer getComputerInTheMatrix(int n_rows,int n_cols){

return matrix[n_rows][n_cols];
}
```

is it right this method?

Comment: You aren't using `n_rows` or `n_cols`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Oli said, try:

```
return matrix[n_rows][n_cols];
```